# Adding content to PDF based on some placeholder area in iText and Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a requirement where I need to put signature, name and job title to PDFs. The position of this data to be placed varies from PDF to PDF. For example for a PDF it might be at certain x,y and say page no 5 whilst for other PDF it might be in page no 8.

For now I have done the implementation for a specific PDF type by choosing the page number and the x,y location of the signature.

Is there a way we can add some placeholder or some identifier in the PDF so that in my iText code I can search for that placeholder, gets its x,y and then insert my signature data at that location.

Comment: The canonical placeholders would be AcroForm form fields. In your code you then have the choice of either simply reading the position of those form fields, manually drawing your replacement there, and removing the fields, or filling the fields and flattening them.